# Can't change whole number to number with 1 decimal point

Tags: python

This program coverts pounds to ounces and kilograms using minimum value, maximum value, and steps.

```
import numbers


minVal = 0
maxVal = 0
steps = 0
ounces = 0
kilograms = 0

minVal = int(input("Enter the minimum value: "))
maxVal = int(input("Enter the maximum value: "))
steps = int(input("Enter the value of the steps: "))

print("_" * 35)
print("")
print("Pounds", "Ounces", "Kilograms")

for i in range(minVal, maxVal + 1, steps):
    print("\n")
    for z in range(1, 2, steps):
        ounces = i * 16
    for x in range(1, 2, steps):
        kilograms = (i * 0.453592)
        print("%4d" % i, "%6d " % ounces,"%6d " % kilograms, end = "")
```

For some reason the kilogram part is only printing the value as a whole number. I want to make it only 1 decimal point.

Comment: [pyformat.info](https://pyformat.info/)

Comment: `%d` is for integers. For one decimal point, do `%.1f` https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This is an **interactive** community. Interact with the community so they can tell if your question has been answered. If an answer meets your needs accept the answer. If your question has not been answered add comments. Possibly clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `%.1f` to print kilograms to 1 decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

Changed `"%6d " % kilograms` to `"%.1f " % kilograms`:

```
import numbers

minVal = 0
maxVal = 0
steps = 0
ounces = 0
kilograms = 0

minVal = int(input("Enter the minimum value: "))
maxVal = int(input("Enter the maximum value: "))
steps = int(input("Enter the value of the steps: "))

print("_" * 35)
print("")
print("Pounds", "Ounces", "Kilograms")

for i in range(minVal, maxVal + 1, steps):
    print("\n")
    for z in range(1, 2, steps):
        ounces = i * 16
    for x in range(1, 2, steps):
        kilograms = (i * 0.453592)
        print("%4d" % i, "%6d " % ounces,"%.1f " % kilograms, end = "")
```

Output:

```
Pounds Ounces Kilograms


   1     16  0.5

   3     48  1.4

   5     80  2.3

   7    112  3.2

   9    144  4.1
```